# MySQLI INSERT query is executed twice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
// open the database connection
require_once('php/db/connect.php');
// set a log file
$logFile = 'log/php.log';
// set the error and the doCommit to false
$error = false;
$doCommit = false;
// build the query
$query = "SELECT name,gender,email,country FROM tmp_backer WHERE backerid = ?";
// prepare the query
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    // bind the parameters
    $id = $postArray['backerid'];
    $stmt->bind_param('s',  $id);
    // execute the query
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // the query is executed!
        $stmt->store_result();
        $tmpArray = array();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $name,$gender,$email,$country);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // clear the parameters
        $query = '';
        // copy everything to the table 'backer'
        // build the query
        $query = "INSERT INTO backer (backerid,name,gender,email,country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        // prepare the query
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            // bind the parameters
            $stmt->bind_param(
                'ssiss',        
                $id,
                $name,
                $gender,
                $email,
                $country
            );
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                // the query is executed!
                // set doCommit to true
                $doCommit = true;
            } else {
                // the query could not be executed
                // log this into the log file and send the visitor back to the become a backer page
                error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' | query could not be executed (INSERT query) '.$stmt->error.PHP_EOL,3,$logFile);
                $error = true;
            };
        } else {
            // the query is invalid
            // log this into the log file and send the visitor back to the become a backer page
            error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' | query is invalid (INSERT query) '.$stmt->error.PHP_EOL,3,$logFile);
            $error = true;
        };
    } else {
        // the query could not be executed
        // log this into the log file and send the visitor back to the become a backer page
        error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' | query could not be executed (SELECT query) '.$stmt->error.PHP_EOL,3,$logFile);
        $error = true;
    };
} else {
    // the query is invalid
    // log this into the log file and send the visitor back to the become a backer page
    error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' | query is invalid (SELECT query) '.$stmt->error.PHP_EOL,3,$logFile);
    $error = true;
};
// check if there where any errors whilst preparing/executing
// the query
if ($error == true) {
    // there were errors
    $mysqli->rollback();
    exit();
} else {
    // there were no errors
    // doCommit was set to true
    if ($doCommit == true) {
        $mysqli->commit();
    };
};
// close the db connection
require_once('php/db/close.php');
```

The **second** query is executed twice, because I get an error in the log file containing the following text:

> 2015-09-14 21:14:12 | query could not be executed (INSERT query) Duplicate entry 'qzdkzkdjzdk' for key 'PRIMARY'

The `backerID` is a random key generated, and is the primary key (field: `backerid`) in both tables. The query WORKS, so the data is copied from the table tmp_backer to backer, but the problem is that the page is not shown (because the second time the INSERT query is executed, it encounters an error so it goes to the part where it is like: `$mysqli->rollback(); exit();`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: redirect after inserting....you're leaving the user on this page so when they hit refresh it tries to insert again....

Comment: You're reusing `$stmt` all over the place and inside loops

Comment: if the query runs twice, then your code is running twice...

Comment: @MarcB how do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

Remove this line:

```
if ($doCommit == true) {
    $mysqli->commit();
};
```

and replace it with:

```
$mysqli->commit();
```

since `if($error == true)` has been called, nothing else will go further after "else" but if it is "false" and since it is "false" `$doCommit` must be "true", so, automatically "commit it" rather than call it back. The thing is, you made `$doCommit` to activate twice. First, by the regular call and once again when you asked for "it" if the result is true.